# hdfs zkfc –formatZK error

Tags: hadoop, apache-zookeeper

I have a cluster consists of three nodes

```
hadoop-master (namenode) 192.168.4.128
hadoop-slave-1 (secondary name node ) 192.168.4.111
hadoop-slave-3 (data node ) 192.168.4.106
```

`jps` command on hadoop-master shows

```
15799 JournalNode

15929 Jps

14978 QuorumPeerMain
```

but when executing this command `hdfs zkfc –formatZK` on namenode 
I am getting this error

```
17/03/30 07:33:09 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Session: 0x15b1ecb76480000 closed
17/03/30 07:33:09 FATAL tools.DFSZKFailoverController: Got a fatal error, exiting now
org.apache.hadoop.HadoopIllegalArgumentException: Bad argument: –formatZK
        at org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController.badArg(ZKFailoverController.java:251)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController.doRun(ZKFailoverController.java:214)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController.access$000(ZKFailoverController.java:61)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController$1.run(ZKFailoverController.java:172)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController$1.run(ZKFailoverController.java:168)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.doAsLoginUserOrFatal(SecurityUtil.java:415)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ha.ZKFailoverController.run(ZKFailoverController.java:168)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.DFSZKFailoverController.main(DFSZKFailoverController.java:181)
17/03/30 07:33:09 WARN ha.ActiveStandbyElector: Ignoring stale result from old client with sessionId 0x15b1ecb76480000
17/03/30 07:33:09 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: EventThread shut down
```

my `zoo.cfg` is

```
initLimit=10

syncLimit=5

dataDir=/usr/local/zookeeper/data/

clientPort=2181

DataLogDir=/usr/local/log/

server.1=hadoop-master:2888:3888

server.2=hadoop-slave-1:2889:3889

server.3=hadoop-slave-2:2890:3890
```

my `slaves` file is

```
hadoop-slave-1
hadoop-slave-2
hadoop-master
```

my `core-site.xml`

```
  <property>
                 <name>dfs.tmp.dir</name>
                 <value>/opt/hadoop/data15</value>
       </property>
        <property>
           <name>fs.default.name</name>
           <value>hdfs://hadoop-master:8020</value>
       </property>
       <property>
           <name>dfs.permissions</name>
           <value>false</value>
       </property>
       <property>
           <name>dfs.journalnode.edits.dir</name>
           <value>/usr/local/journal/node/local/data</value>
       </property>

        <property>

                <name>fs.defaultFS</name>

                <value>hdfs://mycluster</value>

        </property>


        <property>

                <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>

                <value>/tmp</value>


  </property>
```

my `hdfs-site.xml` is

```
 <property>
                 <name>dfs.replication</name>
                 <value>2</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                 <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
                 <value>/opt/hadoop/data16</value>
                 <final>true</final>
        </property>
        <property>
                 <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
                 <value>/opt/hadoop/data17</value>
                 <final>true</final>
        </property>

        <property>
                <name>dfs.webhdfs.enabled</name>
                <value>true</value>
        </property>
        <property>
                <name>dfs.namenode.secondary.http-address</name>
                <value>hadoop-slave-1:50090</value>
        </property>

       <property>

        <name>dfs.nameservices</name>

        <value>mycluster</value>

        <final>true</final>

    </property>

    <property>

        <name>dfs.ha.namenodes.mycluster</name>

        <value>hadoop-master,hadoop-slave-1</value>

        <final>true</final>

    </property>

    <property>

        <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.mycluster.hadoop-master</name>

        <value>hadoop-master:8020</value>

    </property>

    <property>

        <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.mycluster.hadoop-slave-1</name>

        <value>hadoop-slave-1:8020</value>

    </property>

    <property>

        <name>dfs.namenode.http-address.mycluster.hadoop-master</name>

        <value>hadoop-master:50070</value>

    </property>

    <property>

        <name>dfs.namenode.http-address.mycluster.hadoop-slave-1</name>

        <value>hadoop-slave-1:50070</value>

    </property>

    <property>

        <name>dfs.namenode.shared.edits.dir</name>

        <value>qjournal://hadoop-master:8485;hadoop-slave-2:8485;hadoop-slave-1:8485/mycluster</value>

    </property>

    <property>

        <name>dfs.ha.automatic-failover.enabled</name>

        <value>true</value>

    </property>

    <property>

        <name>ha.zookeeper.quorum</name>

        <value>hadoop-master:2181,hadoop-slave-1:2181,hadoop-slave-2:2181</value>

    </property>

    <property>

        <name>dfs.ha.fencing.methods</name>

        <value>sshfence</value>

    </property>

    <property>

        <name>dfs.ha.fencing.ssh.private-key-files</name>

        <value>root/.ssh/id_rsa</value>

    </property>


    <property>

        <name>dfs.ha.fencing.ssh.connect-timeout</name>

        <value>3000</value>

    </property>
```

i have applied `stop-dfs.sh` in all nodes before executing `hdfs zkfc –formatZK` in name node(hadoop-master)

are there any wrong configuration
 and is it neccesary to issue `hdfs namenode -format` before executing

```
 hdfs zkfc –formatZK
```

Comment: Did you copy this command `hdfs zkfc –formatZK` from somewhere? Try this `hdfs zkfc -formatZK`. If you notice the `-` is different.

Comment: i still get same error when issuing command  hdfs zkfc -formatZK but when running jps on name node my out put is 15799 JournalNode
17124 DataNode
14978 QuorumPeerMain
17595 Jps
16785 DFSZKFailoverController so i think every thing is right isn't it

Comment: now if iam issuing  hdfs haadmin -getServiceState hadoop-master
on name node hadoop-master iam getting the out put  17/03/30 10:04:30 INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: hadoop-master/192.168.4.128:8020. Already tried 0 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=1, sleepTime=1000 MILLISECONDS)
Operation failed: Call From hadoop-master/192.168.4.128 to hadoop-master:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused  what does that refers to

Comment: I don't see namenode listed in your `jps` output.

Comment: my last output of jps on namenode (hadoop-master) after issuing command start-all.sh is    19807 DFSZKFailoverController
19668 JournalNode
19910 ResourceManager
19465 DataNode
20013 NodeManager
20325 Jps
14978 QuorumPeerMain
        why did name node disappered and iam still facing the same error     when issuing command hdfs haadmin -getServiceState hadoop-master any help please ?

Comment: Please check the namenode logs for errors, they will be stored under `$HADOOP_HOME/logs/` directory. Also I see that the hadoop configuration properties needs some fixing. Errors should guide you.

Comment: is there any way to attach my log file hadoop-root-namenode-hadoop-master here  or i should open a new question because comment format is not enough to clarify my points

Comment: you can edit this question itself. Post only the error from the log file instead of entire file content.

Comment: i verified the log and I think that the problem iam facing now , which is there is no current name node in my Hadoop cluster 
even though issued start-all.sh from namenode(Hadoop-master)


is because of these property in hdfs-site.xml
<property>

        <name>dfs.namenode.shared.edits.dir</name>

        <value>qjournal://hadoop-master:8485;hadoop-slave-2:8485;hadoop-slave-1:8485/mycluster</value>

    </property>

Comment: Because the log of Hadoop-root-namenode-hadoop-master.log
Shows these following errors 

org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.qjournal.client.QuorumException: Got too many exceptions to achieve quorum size 2/3. 3 exceptions thrown:
192.168.4.128:8485: Journal Storage Directory /usr/local/journal/node/local/data/mycluster not formatted

     192.168.4.111:8485: Call From hadoop-master/192.168.4.128 to

Comment: hadoop-slave-1:8485 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
    
    192.168.4.106:8485: Call From hadoop-master/192.168.4.128 to hadoop-slave-2:8485 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
    
    2.168.4.128:8485: Call From hadoop-master/192.168.4.128 to hadoop-master:8485 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused For more details

Comment: i want to mention that i had never formatted the name node after zoo keeper start